# Subset each dataframe in array and store as new dataframe object each time in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I currently have 5 dataframes in Pandas: a, b, c, d and e. Each of these files have a 'time' column, and I am looking to only extract the rows where 'time' = 0.

The most straightforward way I know is to simply subset, for example:

```
a_base = a[a['time']==0]
```

However, I am looking for a better way then copying the same line 5 times for each dataframe. Looping over an array of the dataframe names means I have to make a new variable each time. Is there a better way to do this in less lines of code?

Comment: Have you tried doing it as a list comprehension? Just put all dataframes into a list and iterate over them to get your subsets. The result would be another list that you could extract as ``a_base, b_base, c_base, d_base, e_base = subset_list``.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with the result. How big the dataframes are etc. You might not need to assign your result to another dataframe at all if you are only using it once. You can use callable indexing like

```
a.loc[lambda x:x['time']==0]
```

This will filter your dataframe and you can chain any method you want.